# Latex algorithm line spacing

Tags: latex, pdflatex

I have created an algorithm in latex but there is some extra line spacing being inserted.
I currently have the following code

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}

This this this

\begin{algorithm}
    \algblock[TryCatchFinally]{try}{endtry}
    \algcblock[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{finally}{endtry}
    \algcblockdefx[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{catch}{endtry}
    [1]{\textbf{catch} #1}
    {\textbf{end try}}  
    \caption{Task}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure {Task Check}{}        
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{$aaaaaaaaa\textunderscore aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call\textunderscore service,
            args=(
            "aaaaa\textunderscore aaaaaa\textunderscore generation\textunderscore aaaa",
            Craaaaalan,
            "load\textunderscore plan\textunderscore aaaa")
            )$}
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{$aaaa-aaaaaaaaa\textunderscore aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call\textunderscore service,
            args=(
            "aaaaa\textunderscore aaaaaa\textunderscore generation\textunderscore aaaa",
            Craaaaalan,
            "load\textunderscore plan\textunderscore aaaa")
            )$}
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{$aaaaaa\textunderscore aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call\textunderscore service,
            args=(
            "aaaaa\textunderscore aaaaaa\textunderscore generation\textunderscore aaaa",
            Craaaaalan,
            "load\textunderscore plan\textunderscore aaaa")
            )$}     
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

and the output is somewhat like this:

[image: Latex output pdf look]

The three states in the images are identical service calls with a minor change. The minor change is the use of diffent words and hence a difference length. The sample code attached contains the accurate length. The output of **State 7** is what I need for the other states as well but due to some extra words it does not follow the format. Any idea how to correct **State 5** and **State 6 ** so that it looks like **State 7**?

Color difference with and without math mode

[image]

Thanks

Comment: please make a compilable [mre]

Comment: You should never abuse math mode to typeset multiletter words. On of the consequences is that line breaking won't work. Have a look at the `listings` package instead, this allows line breaks in verbatim material. Or use one of the package dedicated for algorithms.

Comment: There are no formula in there. They are just a normal english words with some naming convention being met. I edited the code so that you can easily compile it. Thanks

Comment: This is still a code fragment which can't be compiled. The whole document structure, packages etc are missing.

Comment: "There are no formula in there" That's why you should never ever use math mode for this

Comment: I added the neccessary. And I used a template for wrting the algorithms. Just followed the format. Where exactly in this code do I define the math mode?

Comment: That's still not compilable. The documentclass is missing, the package are at the wrong place

Comment: You force it to use math mode with `$...$`

Answer (score 2):

Math mode is totally unsuitable to set verbatim content like variable names. The missing line breaks should be the least of your worries. The kerning is messed up, the quotation marks are wrong, minus signs instead of hyphens...

You could try with raggedright normal text, but I would typeset such things as source code, e.g. using the `listings` package:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \algblock[TryCatchFinally]{try}{endtry}
    \algcblock[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{finally}{endtry}
    \algcblockdefx[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{catch}{endtry}
    [1]{\textbf{catch} #1}
    {\textbf{end try}}  
    \caption{Task}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure {Task Check}{}        
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{\raggedright\lstinline{aaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call_service, args=("aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", Craaaaalan, "load_plan_aaaa"))}}
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{\raggedright\lstinline{aaaa-aaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call_service, args=("aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", Craaaaalan, "load_plan_aaaa"))}}
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{\raggedright\lstinline{aaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call_service, args=("aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", Craaaaalan, "load_plan_aaaa"))}}     
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or if you insist on italic font:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\itshape, breaklines}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \algblock[TryCatchFinally]{try}{endtry}
    \algcblock[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{finally}{endtry}
    \algcblockdefx[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{catch}{endtry}
    [1]{\textbf{catch} #1}
    {\textbf{end try}}  
    \caption{Task}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure {Task Check}{}        
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{\raggedright\lstinline{aaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call_service, args=("aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", Craaaaalan, "load_plan_aaaa"))}}
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{\raggedright\lstinline{aaaa-aaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call_service, args=("aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", Craaaaalan, "load_plan_aaaa"))}}
        \State \parbox[t]{313pt}{\raggedright\lstinline{aaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(aaaaaa=call_service, args=("aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", Craaaaalan, "load_plan_aaaa"))}}     
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or maybe even with as real listings with linebreaks etc. to make things more readable:

```
\documentclass{article}



\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily, breaklines}

\begin{document}

\begin{algorithm}
    \algblock[TryCatchFinally]{try}{endtry}
    \algcblock[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{finally}{endtry}
    \algcblockdefx[TryCatchFinally]{TryCatchFinally}{catch}{endtry}
    [1]{\textbf{catch} #1}
    {\textbf{end try}}  
    \caption{Task}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Procedure {Task Check}{}        
        \State \vspace*{-1.46\baselineskip}\begin{lstlisting}
aaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(
  aaaaaa=call_service, 
  args=(
    "aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", 
    Craaaaalan, 
    "load_plan_aaaa"
  )
)
\end{lstlisting}
        \State \vspace*{-1.46\baselineskip}\begin{lstlisting}
aaaa-aaaaaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(
  aaaaaa=call_service, 
  args=(
    "aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", 
    Craaaaalan, 
    "load_plan_aaaa"
  )
)
        \end{lstlisting}
        \State \vspace*{-1.46\baselineskip}\begin{lstlisting}
aaaaaa_aaaaaaa = Thread(
  aaaaaa=call_service, 
  args=(
    "aaaaa_aaaaaa_generation_aaaa", 
    Craaaaalan, 
    "load_plan_aaaa"
  )
)
        \end{lstlisting}     
        \EndProcedure
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I want to keep the font that is used in the math mode. I have 10 other algorithms that use the same font, style and color. Any way i could use the same font, style and clolor without math mode?

Comment: @MuhammadMustafa Math font is NOT suitable. You should NOT use it for your other 10 algos. If you want a similar text font, use `\itshape` instead of `\ttfamily`

Comment: Thanks. There are some mathematics termed involved as well in some algorithms. I want keep a homogeneous format for all algorithms. Thanks for the input. he style and font is the same but the there is a difference in colour. This one way is too black than the math mode one . A visual difference is added in the main question as an image.

Comment: The new screenshot is not the result of the MWE. You must be using some package that changes the font to sans serif

Comment: @MuhammadMustafa And for your other algorithm: even if they contain math and you therefore have to use math mode, you should never set multiletter variable names in this mode. Have a look at the `\text{...}` macro from the `amsmath` package to set them as text.

Comment: Its a 200 page document so it has some default template setting I guess. State 5 is the output from your answer. Looks great. But the old versions of my code show a different outlook in State 6 and State 7. Is it possible to have the old outlook as in State 6 and State 7 to remain as the default and the new outlook suggested by you follows that?

Comment: @MuhammadMustafa State 5 is not the output from my code. I added a screenshot of my code using italic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0FGx5.png

Comment: @MuhammadMustafa And don't take this personally, but if your template produce output like 6 or 7 in your image, throw away the template. That just hurts the eye.

Comment: Hahaha. I completely understand. That is what I am to. Thanks a lot for your help. I am using your template. I will have to change the default font details for the algorthims part to make it homogeneous for the whole book. Have a nice day. Cheers